# Can you help me prepopulate an option box with data from an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build option boxes that, when rendered, will be prepopulated with the assigned user's name and surname. Currently, every time the page is rendered, the option boxes populate with the first option in the list, so it looks as though the data has not been saved, but in fact, it has been. Consider that the user's name and surname are stored in another table of the database, associated with the userId.

Thank You.

```
render() {
return (
    <div key={this.props.task.id} className="taskCard">
        <div className="taskCardBody">
            <h3 className="taskCardTitle">
                <p>{this.props.task.taskDesc}</p>
                <p>{this.props.task.dueDate}</p>
                <p>{this.props.task.note}</p>

                <label htmlFor="assignTo" placeholder="Assign To">Assign To</label>
                <select className="form-control"
                    onInput={this.assignTo}
                    id="assignTo" placeholder="Assign To">
                    <option value="" defaultValue="" ></option>
                    {this.props.employees.map(employee => (
                        <option key={employee.id} id={employee.id} value={employee.id}>
                            {employee.name} {employee.surname}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>

                <br></br>

                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`/tasks/${this.props.task.id}/edit`)}>Edit Task</button>
                <br></br>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteTask(this.props.task.id)}
                    className="btn btn-danger">Delete Task
                    </button>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

I would like the option that is displayed on render to be "Joe Smith" if Joe Smith has been assigned a particular task. Otherwise, if no one has been assigned, to render "some default string".

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `assignTo` function passes the employee id to the state, you can prepopulate the state with that and then set the value of your `<select>` to `this.state.selectedEmployee` (or whatever you named it).